# How to access sub level JSON trough Django

Tags: json, django

So, I get this JSON from Django:

```
{'something' : 
    {'value':'somethingName','editable':'false'}
},
{'somethingElse': 
    {'value':'somethingElseName','editable':'true'}
}
```

And show it like this:

```
{% for key, value in obj.items %}
    {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is `{{ value }}` returns `{'value':'somethingName','editable':'false'}`, and I can't access `value` or `editable` trough `{{ value.value }}` or `{{ value.editable }}`.

I'd like to show `{{ value.value }}` as `somethingName` instead of the entire JSON.

Is there a way to access 'sub-level' JSON trough Django itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use template variable name as a dictionary key using the [`.` notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables). The second `value` in `value.value` is not interpreted as a string `value` because you have a variable name `value` in the loop.

Just rename `key` and `value` to `obj_key` and `obj_value` respectively:

```
{% for obj_key, obj_value in obj.items %}
    {{ obj_key }} : {{ obj_value.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("""
... {% for obj_key, obj_value in obj.items %}
...     {{ obj_key }} : {{ obj_value.value }}
... {% endfor %}""")
>>> obj = {'something' : {'value':'somethingName','editable':'false'}}

>>> t.render(Context({'obj': obj}))
u'something : somethingName'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Really? Some people at the python chat told me it wasn't possible. I'll test this out and accept it if it worked :)

Comment: @AdriánSalgado well, there is a demo in the answer - it's from a real django 1.6 shell :)

Comment: Wow, this is pretty old. I'm not sure how I solved it, but I'm not working on that app anymore, not even working with Django nowadays. Thanks!